# Wix - How to get a relative path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, wix3.5

I need to reference some dlls files in my wix project, and i need to user relative path. If i use absolute path like this

```
C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\any\other\folder
```

it works perfectly, but i need a relative path like this:

```
../bin/dll
```

but it is unable to find the folder.

This is the "ComponentGroup" section where i need to get the dll folder

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="DllsComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Source="../bin/dll">      
  <Component Id="EntityFramework.dll">
    <File Name="EntityFramework.dll" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll">
    <File Name="EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="EntityFramework.SqlServerd.xml">
    <File Name="EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="EntityFramework.xml">
    <File Name="EntityFramework.xml" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ParodosService.exe.config">
    <File Name="ParodosService.exe.config" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

and the wix project structure is this:

```
ParodosService.Setup
|_bin
   |_dll
      |_EntityFramework.dll
      |_EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
      |_other files...
   |_Debug
   |_Release
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use predefined directory properties from the list 
[System Folder Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(VS.85).aspx#system_folder_properties)

Set the closest in the directory table and than use it in the source attribute.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder">
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Source attribute:

```
Source="$(var.DesktopFolder)../bin/dll
```